# Magento 2 - How to override module from vendor?

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, overrides

I try to change some "view" files from a module called **Amasty_MegaMenu**.

I installed the module via composer. It is located in **vendor\amasty\mega-menu**.

So I created `app/code/Amasty/MegaMenu` with these files:

**app/code/Amasty/MegaMenu/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Amasty_MegaMenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

and **app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Amasty Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2020 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
 * @package Amasty_MegaMenu
 */
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amasty_MegaMenu" setup_version="1.5.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Amasty_Base"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

which I have copied from the original vendor module.

Then I added the files which I want to replace

**app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\view\base\web\css\source\module\_variables.less**

**app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\view\base\web\css\source\module\_helpers.less**

**app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\view\base\web\css\source\mkcss\ammenu.css**

Then I executed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` but I get:

> Autoload error: Module 'Amasty_MegaMenu' from
>   '/home/company/redesign.company.com/app/code/Amasty/MegaMenu' has been
>   already defined in
>   '/home/company/redesign.company.de/vendor/amasty/mega-menu'.

Comment: You don't need to create a module for that, just place it in your current theme like this : `app/design/frontend/Your-theme/theme-name/Amasty_MegaMenu/web/css/source/mkcss/ammenu.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just trying to change view files, then you don't need to create a new module at all. Instead you can just create them under the app/design folder to override them with your theme. For example if I wanted to override the following vendor files

```
vendor\amasty\mega-menu\src\view\base\web\css\source\module_variables.less
vendor\amasty\mega-menu\src\view\base\web\css\source\module_helpers.less
vendor\amasty\mega-menu\src\view\base\web\css\source\mkcss\ammenu.css
```

We can use the following template to override web files in a module.

```
app/design/frontend/[ThemeVendor]/[Theme]/[ModuleVendor_ModuleName]
```

An example extending the amasty files onto the Magento Luma theme would be.

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Amasty_MegaMenu/web/css/source/module_variables.less
app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Amasty_MegaMenu/web/css/source/module_helpers.less
app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Amasty_MegaMenu/web/css/source/mkcss/ammenu.css
```

---

But to answer why are are getting the error message, Magento treats all modules in `app/code` and `vendor` as a big pool. So since you name your new module `Amasty_MegaMenu` it clashes with the Amasty one in vendor. So the options you would have would be.

## 1. Rename your module

This would be the ideal solution, generally when overriding modules I would advise to use your own Vendor prefix to show who created the override. So for example you could name the module `Sam_AmastyMegaMenu`.

In your `etc\module.xml` file you would add a dependency for the original module.

Then because we want to override stylesheets, we would need to find where they are included (layout xml / templates etc). Then override the relevant layout xml / template to use the asset from our new module.

## 2. Move module to app/code

This is the less ideal solution as you would have to manage the module updates manually, and editing vendor files would cause you to lose modifications during updates. But you would uninstall the module from composer `composer remove amasty/mega-menu`. Then download their file archive (a zip file i think) and extract that into your `app/code` folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you remove the module name database

> Please going the database and open the setup_module and remove the your module name

And after add the your files like Your **app/code** file path:-

**app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\view\base\web\css\source\module_variables.less**

**app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\view\base\web\css\source\module_helpers.less**

**app\code\Amasty\MegaMenu\view\base\web\css\source\mkcss\ammenu.css**

And after run the **php bin/magento s:up**

Hope help you

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the module from `setup_module` but it does still not work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove entry from`setup_module` table.
2. Also if you find it's entry in app/etc/config.php , you should delete it from there as well.
3. Now run following commands

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> chmod 777 -R var pub generate

If you sill getting error then run below command in magento root directory and check.

> composer dump-autoload